# path variable inconsistency when using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, path

I did this:

```
ssh me@remote which hg
```

returned nothing presumably because it couldn't find hg.

So then I did this:

```
ssh me@remote echo $PATH
```

which returned this long mess: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/bin

Then I did this:

```
ssh me@remote
<after getting logged in to the remote computer>
which hg
/opt/bin/hg
```

Why would the server be able to find the hg binary in one instance, but not in both?  What do you have to do to fix it so the

```
ssh me@remote which hg
```

works?

Comment: Try `ssh me@remote echo $(which hg)`, although I don't know why it wouldn't work the other way. And `which` should complain if it doesn't find the program, so it's probably not a problem with `PATH` not being set.

Comment: I have always seen which either print the path to the program with the name points to (i.e. which ls would print /bin/ls) and if there is no such program, it prints nothing, but it returns 1.

Comment: I don't have your vast experience, but on my system it complains rather bitterly. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I tried that suggestion but it printed the location of the hg binary on my local computer.

Comment: Arrghh, of course! (Why didn't I think of that.) So it's printing your local PATH too. What does `ssh me@remote echo \$PATH` return?

Comment: It returns this /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/syno/bin which is clearly missing where the hg is, which is why which hg fails.  The question then is how to get it so that a non-interactive ssh has more in the path.

Comment: Perhaps `ssh me@remove bash -c "which hg"` (or whichever shell you want).

Answer (score 0):

This should work (as ooga mentioned).

```
ssh me@remote "which hg || whereis hg"
```